# Multiple Jquery Countdown showing NaN

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have been working on my own costum Javascript Countdown for multiple countdowns at the site, but the date doesn't count correctly.

I have this javascript for displaying time counter :

```
$(function(){

    $('.countdown').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        ts = new Date($this.data('ts')),
        newYear = true;

        if((new Date()) > ts){
            newYear = false;
        }
        $this.countdown({
            timestamp   : ts,
            callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
                var message = "";
                message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
                $this.next().html(message);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

this is how my table looked :

```
id    |      tgl_close1     |   idrek
1     | 2014-11-25 08:00:00 |      1
2     | 2014-11-26 10:00:00 |      1
3     | 2014-11-26 12:10:00 |      1
```

i multiply the countdown by foreach but it always show 'NaN' instead of number :

```
<?php 
$fetch = mysql_query("select tgl_close1
                      from tba
                      where idrek = 1");

/* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $tgl_close1[] = date("Y, n-1, j, G, i, s", strtotime($row['tgl_close1']));


}
foreach ($tgl_close1 as $tglclose){
 ?>
<br>
<table border="0"><tr><td>
<div class="countdown" data-ts="<?php echo $tglclose"></div>
<p class="note"></p>    
</td></tr></table>


<?php
}
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('.countdown').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        ts = new Date($this.data('ts')),
        newYear = true;

        if((new Date()) > ts){
            newYear = false;
        }
        $this.countdown({
            timestamp   : ts,
            callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
                var message = "";
                message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
                $this.next().html(message);
            }
        });
    });

});



</script>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried with `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` ? (*Your issue is most likely that it is concatenating it as a string, not adding them together*)

Comment: I'm sorry if i get it wrong, but I want to pass a date, isn't `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` will take it wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

well, i changed my javascript into this :

```
$(function(){

    $('.countdown').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            ts = new Date($('.note').data('ts')),
            newYear = true;

        if((new Date()) > ts){
            newYear = false;
        }
        $this.countdown({
            timestamp   : ts,
            callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){
                var message = "";
                message += days + " hari" + ( days==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += hours + " jam" + ( hours==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += minutes + " menit" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'' ) + ", ";
                message += seconds + " detik" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'' ) + " <br />";
                $this.next().html(message);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

it get the date passed into javascript,but the `$tglclose` that passed into javascript is only the first row, so i have three counter with same time counter..